# How to save and load tensor flow model after using tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Here is the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/input_fn/boston.py

After model is saved in this part:

```
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 10],
                                        model_dir="/tmp/boston_model")

# Fit
regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(training_set), steps=5000)
```

How can I load it and use regressor.evaluate() and regressor.predict() after loading it?
Would I have to use regressor.export_savedmodel() but then how would the serving_input_fn be defined?

Comment: For loading, you call, regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,hidden_units=[10, 10], model_dir="/tmp/boston_model"). It will load the model from 'tmp/boston_model' and then use regressor.evaluate() or regressor.predict() to evaluate or predict.

Comment: op=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1,l1_regularization_strength=1.0, l2_regularization_strength=1.0)
But if I am using the tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols,optimizer=op, model_dir="/tmp/boston_model")

I will have to mention the optimizer again and train the regressor again using fit. Is there a way to just start evaluate() and predict() after loading the model?

Comment: What do you mean by your previous question?. Call the method what ever you trained for and then call evaluate() and predict().

Comment: I am trying to first save the model, then the path where the model is saved will be passed to some other program which will load the model from the directory where model is saved.
Suppose I call the function:
     
    `def loadModel(model_path):
        
e = getModel(model_path) //getModel: will be what?
        e.evaluate()
        e.predict() // and the predictions will be the output of the model`

Comment: You can't confuse it more. There two functions train() and  test(). Your model is `AnyClassifier`. In `train` you call `AnyClassifier(..., model_dir)` and then call `fit()` method. In your `test` you call `AnyClassifier(..., model_dir)`  and then can call evaluate() and predict() methods. In the `test` case, your model will find a trained model in the `model_dir`and will load the trained model params. Edit your original question, all there questions you have asked doesn't correspond to the same piece of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have made the correction, yes you are right I am also trying on a different code I will add a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say there are two functions `train()` and `test()` and your model is `AnyClassifier`. In train you call `AnyClassifier(..., model_dir)` and then call the `fit()` method. In your test case you call `AnyClassifier(..., model_dir)` and then can call `evaluate()` and `predict()` methods. In the test case, your model will find a trained model in the `model_dir` and will load the trained model params.